Error after firebase linking to flutter project
[app/build.gradle]
(https://i.sstatic.net/xFBEUbUi.png)
[main.dart]
(https://i.sstatic.net/ARYitV8J.png)
its my terminal
E/flutter ( 4746): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
E/flutter ( 4746):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
E/flutter ( 4746):      at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter ( 4746):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/flutter ( 4746):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/flutter ( 4746):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter ( 4746): , null)
E/flutter ( 4746): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter ( 4746): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4746): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 4746): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4746): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 4746): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4746): #3      main (package:new_hemobridge/main.dart:7:2)
E/flutter ( 4746): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4746):
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...                          709ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on sdk gphone x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:63008/v8-J0gdc5eg=/     
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:63008/v8-J0gdc5eg=/


i dont know,everyone suggest check the google service json file but its all right,doublechecked the dependencies and pubsec,yaml file nothing sus caught my eyes .

I don't know,everyone suggest check the google service json file but its all right,doublechecked the dependencies and pubsec,yaml file nothing sus caught my eyes

(not the downvoter) Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You have to add options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, as a property of Firebase.initializeApp
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

and to do that you need firebase_options.dart file
Here's how I add Firebase to the environment and linked it with flutter:

Create a firebase project from firebase console

Followed the instructions in this FlutterFire, so that I can link firebase project with flutter project

After that run the app to make sure that everything is ok.

I need the firebase_CLI to add firebase_options.dart file to the project so I can use DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform in the main.dart

I downloaded CLI from here and installed it (which you can login to your firebase project with your Gmail directly).

I downloaded last version of node.js from here

It suppose to take a while to be installed with powerShell

Make sure that these three paths is added to system variables && personal variables


  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
  C:\Program Files\nodejs


Run node --version && npm --version to make sure that everything ok

In the command prompt run npm install -g firebase-tools

Then dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

If the vsCode opened close it and open it again

In the directory of your flutter project in vsCode run flutterfire configure

You can also read these instructions

It suppose to run and everything is ok.


